# Is Comparing last modified time stamp of src and class file is the best way to make sure that class file is the latest one?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am trying t o make sure that the .class file am selected is being generated fro the latest src file. Build is triggered by another mechanism. Hence I want to double check this before executing my task. Currently I am planning to compare the last modified time of src and class fle to make sure that class is being created after the src modification time.

I want to know if this is the proper way of doing this? Or there are any other alternatives?

I am trying to copy a class file from its location. My application is not going to compile src and generate class files. It just copies a required class file from target to dest. Before making the copy operation, but i want to ensure that class file am copying is the latest one.

Comment: Just delete all class files before compiling. Then you know for sure that every class file is the latest. This is how most build tools work.

Comment: question edited with more info

Comment: The Java compiler already does this job admirably. Don't re-invent it.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a script to clean all the class files before build. That is the simplest and the surest way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reverse engineerging to this class, so to check that your changes is there.
You could use this tool http://jd.benow.ca/ convert from .class to readable .java code.